# .NET Core 2 HttpClient always returns statuscode 200

Tags: redirect, httpclient, asp.net-core-2.0

I started with a tool to check for redirects in .net 4.6. With `HttpClient` I checked for redirects (`AllowAutoRedirect = true` in the HttpClientHandler) and for sites like http://www.google.com I got a 302 > 200.

Now I'm moving to .net core 2 and using the exact same code I always get a StatusCode 200 with an empty Location header.

Does anyone know if something crucial changed in the .net core 2 implementation of HttpClient?

The code:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = allowAutoRedirect };            

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, url);

    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutAfterMiliseconds);

    var result = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you get the request body?

Comment: AllowAutoRedirect = true, should do the redirect for you. If you want to do it manually set it to false.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, getting the same behavior for .Net Core 2.0 and .Net Framework 4.6. When `AllowAutoRedirect` is false, status code is 302 with `Location` header filled. When `AllowAutoRedirect` is true, status code is expectedly 200 with empty 'Location' header.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning AllowAutoRedirect. I didn't include the variable declaration in my code above, I have been using it incorrect with "true" all the time... It now works as intended. Thanks a lot!